# Embedded graphics in original mail change to attached graphics in reply when using exchangelib in python

Tags: exchangelib

We have a python script that replies to incoming emails using exchangelib. User A sends us an email that can contain a picture/graphic (e.g. company logo in signature line). Our script is able to reply to his mail, and user A will get our reply. Unfortunately, the picture/graphic that was embedded in the original mail to us, is now an attached file instead of an embedded picture.
Here is the code that we're using:

```
origmsg.reply(
      subject='Re: ' + origmsg.subject,
      body="This is my reply to your inquiry...."
    )
```

I understand that for new messages the HTML code needs to include a reference to the attached file to make it embedded. How can this be done in a reply?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://ecederstrand.github.io/exchangelib/#attachments has some example of embedding images in emails.

The `.reply()` method is for simple replies. You may need to call `.create_reply()` instead and edit the returned `ReplyToItem` object as needed before calling `.send()` on it.

If you have even more special requirements, you can call `.save()` on the  `ReplyToItem` object to save it as a draft, fetch the draft as a plain `Message` object with `account.drafts.get(id=reply_to_item_id)` and do whatever you need to do before sending the draft.